# rated voltage on power blocks

Tags: adapter, voltage

I recently converted a beer light (plexiglass) using 20 LED's, resisters and a power block rated at 9V but it burned out the LED's.  I When i tested the adapter it was putting out 14V's.

Question:  I then tested several other power blocks i had on hand with varying voltage ratings and found most of them, not all, provided higher voltages that the tag indicated.   What am i to believe when looking at these labels.  I like playing with LED's but need to understand the voltage of these power blocks to ensure they work.

Comment: You might want to ask that on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: LEDs do not burn up because of too much voltage.  LEDs burn up because of too much current.

Answer (score 1):

Those ratings are only specified under the load shown (i.e. if you have a 20V 4A adapter, the voltage should be 20V when drawing 4A).  Most unregulated power supplies, or ones that expect a significant load, will go to a very high voltage when open-circuit.

To ensure the voltage doesn't go too high, you might want to put a high-wattage, low-resistance resistor in parallel with your circuit.  It's wasteful, but if you put enough of a load on the power supply, it will ensure the voltage never goes higher than what one would expect.